# Mounting local volumes to remote docker container, Possible?

Tags: docker, volumes

I'm pretty comfortable using Docker recently, typically to test websites to make sure they run properly on servers before I deploy them.

Typically, I mount my local directory to the locally running image like:

```
docker run -v c:\temp\website:/var/www/html (you get the picture)
```

What I am curious about is if there is a way to mount my local volume to a remote server running docker. I'm pretty sure the answer is no, unless I poke wholes in firewalls and such to make a local volume share externally.

But, I thought I would ask. Docker seems to be doing some amazing things quickly.

Comment: From what I have read docker volumes must exist on the host, they cannot be from a remote source. I've been looking to do the opposite of you want to do. A local container with a remote volume.

Comment: I did a look up for volume drivers and found this: See: [flocker](https://github.com/ScatterHQ/flocker). Which won't help your situation, but provides a way to use remote volumes

Comment: @BenjaminSlabbert , Hi I am trying to do almost the same as you. My production remote docker container is running on Elastibeanstalk on AWS and I want to take a snapshot/copy of its volume and connect my local docker container to it(the purpose is to populate the local env with prod-alike data and testing), can you please reply here with anything you think its useful for this case!?thanks

Comment: Hi @Yusuf, what I would suggest is to create EBS snapshots, see: [EBSSnapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html) this will then create regular backups of your docker volume which you can then use at a later point for testing. I would also recommend that the EBS volume you use for the docker volume and these backups is not the root volume. How to use the remove volume for a local docker container I do not know, but perhaps it is acceptable in your case to download the data to your machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. First **share** your local directory in Windows. Lets assume your shared folder is `\\windowsip\website`.
2. Then login into the remote linux machine where docker engine is running, and be sure you can mount a windows shared folder: `sudo apt install cifs-utils`
3. Try to connect to your share: `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=******,password=******,uid=ubuntu,gid=ubuntu //windowsip/website /home/ubuntu/website`
4. When everything is working lets do the same with docker. Create a named volume as follows: `docker volume create --driver local --opt type=cifs --opt device='//windowsip/website' --opt o='username=*****,password=*****' website`
5. `docker run -v website:/var/www/html`

I know it is an old thread but just I had the same problem, hope it helps to others

Okey Okey I didn't read the last part of the question. Yes, you need to poke holes in the firewall. But still is useful, I have a linux server with docker and I use it via VPN when I work from home in my laptop. The container has local access to everything.

Comment: We don't need VPN here - how about forwarding the local cifs port (445) with the ssh connection?